# TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function caption: 'Student List Loading via Array'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

i have got Above Error when Loading View of Index.
I want Implement JQGrid using jquery grid plugin

i have Include  Number of JS file in View and also CSS for JQGrid. rather than i can not Create Grid by using JQGrid plugin so please help me for that and i have use JQGrid 4.6.0 version so please help me

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqGrid/css/ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Content/jqGrid/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jqGrid/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jqModal.js")"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jquery.jqGrid.js")"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jqDnR.js")"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")"></script>
```

-------------html -------- table for grid ---------
  
        
------------- SCript Part -------------

```
  $(document).ready(function (e)
        {

            $("#student-grid-json").jqGrid({
                url: "/Demo/GetStudents",
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ["Student ID", "Name", "Course", "Year"],
                colModel: [
                            { name: "StudentID", index: "StudentID" },
                            { name: "Name", index: "Name" },
                            { name: "Course", index: "Course" },
                            { name: "Year", index: "Year", sorttype: "int" }
                ],
                rowNum: 50,
                rowList: [20, 50, 100],
                pager: "#pager-json",
                sortname: "StudentID",
                sortorder: "ASC",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Student List - Loading via JSON"
            });

            $("#student-grid-array").navGrid("#pager-json", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });

        });
```

Comment: you didn't set mtype:'GET'

Comment: i thing problem is not controller side because i know that the problem is that i have load wrong JS file in View so please Suggest me to step to develop and which JS File i need to Load in View What's wrong in Declaration of Method to write code for JQGrid..

Answer (score 2):

found the problem.Here is the order for libraries

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link href="~/Content/jqGrid/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqGrid/css/ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="~/Content/jqGrid/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jquery.jqGrid.js")"></script>  
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jqModal.js")"></script>

 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/jqDnR.js")"></script>
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JQGrid/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")"></script>
```

This is the correct order.you put the modal before jqgrid.js which was making problem